# Remove css animation no working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a sliding carousel using JavaScript. Everything works besides for when you want to go back a slide. In the example below, if you're on 'Second', then click 'First', there isn't animation and it goes straight to 'first'. When I check in dev tools, I see the actual CSS animation is there (i.e. CSS `transition`).

I think the problem is, it skips the code on line 19:

```
sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
```

and applies the one on line 25:

```
sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(' + translateXamount + '%)';
```

I want it to go to `translateX(-50%)` then animate to `translateX(0)`. How can I achieve that?

If you have a better, more efficient way of creating a sliding carousel, please post that.

#### CodePen

```js
var sliderInnerWrapper = document.getElementById('sliderInnerWrapper'),
  sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider'),
  arrows = document.getElementsByClassName('arrows'),

  currentSelectedTabContent = sliders[0],
  previousSelectedTabContent = currentSelectedTabContent;

previousSelectedTabContent.style.display = 'block';

var tabChange = function(tab) {
    var selectedIndex = indexInClass(arrows, tab.path[0]),
      translateXamount;
    currentSelectedTabContent = sliders[selectedIndex];

    currentSelectedTabContent.style.display = 'block';
    if (selectedIndex < indexInClass(sliders, previousSelectedTabContent)) {
      translateXamount = 0;
      sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
    } else {
      translateXamount = -50
    }

    sliderInnerWrapper.style.transition = 'transform 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1)';
    sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(' + translateXamount + '%)';
  },
  tabContentAnimationCallback = function() {
    sliderInnerWrapper.style.transition = 'none';
    sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    previousSelectedTabContent.style.display = 'none';
    previousSelectedTabContent = currentSelectedTabContent;
  };

for (var i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {
  arrows[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    tabChange(e);
  });
}
sliderInnerWrapper.addEventListener('transitionend', tabContentAnimationCallback);



function indexInClass(collection, node) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i] === node)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

```css
#sliderOuterWrapper {
  width: 300px;
  /* overflow: hidden;  Enenturally*/
}
#sliderInnerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 600px;
}
.slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
}
.arrows {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderOuterWrapper">
  <div id="sliderInnerWrapper">
    <div class="slider" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-color: purple"></div>
    <div class="slider" style="background-color: cadetblue"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="arrowWrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="tabSliderGroup" checked="true" class="arrows" />First
  <input type="radio" name="tabSliderGroup" class="arrows" />Second
  <input type="radio" name="tabSliderGroup" class="arrows" />Third
  <input type="radio" name="tabSliderGroup" class="arrows" />Fourth
</div>
```

## Update

I just realize that if line 25 only executes from first to second, not from second to first, then `sliderInnerWrapper` will animate to -50%. How can I make it not animate to `-50%`?

**Udated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVXrEe?editors=0010)**

Comment: `tab.path[0]`: `TypeError: tab.path is undefined`

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using chrome, and it works fine.

Comment: Firefox. No idea what Chrome is doing, but `tab` is the event object, and I don't think events have a `path` property.

Comment: I made a `console.log` of tab and here's a snapshot: http://i.imgur.com/ah2XY43.png If you have a better way of getting the clicked radio button then please let me know

Comment: Just updated the CodePen. Let me know if it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/MKrMdr/?editors=0110

I think I fixed it but the `transition: bezier` makes the behavior weird but kinda cool (never seen a slider act like that). Anyways, it's functional in Chrome and Firefox PC for sure this time. *Functional but* not totally stable; if the "arrows: are clicked in a quick succession, it'll end up on a different slide than what was intended. I blame that buggyness on the time of the transition, so try adjusting to go a little faster. The following are the parts I changed. I believe the trouble came from not declaring `flex-wrap: nowrap` on `#sliderInnerWrapper`.

```
#sliderOuterWrapper {
  width: 300px;
 overflow: hidden; 
}

#sliderInnerWrapper {

 display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 600px;

}

currentSelectedTabContent.style.display = "block";
//currentSelectedTabContent.style.visibility = "visible";
if (selectedIndex < indexInClass(sliders, previousSelectedTabContent)) {
  translateXamount = -100;
  sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';
} else {
  translateXamount = -50;
}
```

<del>I changed the event `change` into `click`. The event `change` doesn't do anything until the you `unfocus` or `blur`. I guess Firefox handles `change` by the spec and Chrome goes a little rogue and says, "screw it! I know what you really want to do" Anyways, tested in Chrome and Firefox PC ok.</del>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is still there. The problem is, when 'second' is selected then you select 'first', there isn't animation and `translateX` goes to 0 without the animation.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) in particular this part: *The event will also not fire if the animated element becomes display: none before the transition fully completes.*

Comment: The element gets `display:none` at the callback function. It then becomes `display: block` before any animation happens.

Comment: @Jessica Check this out, it's behavior is actually stable as in it'll go to where you want it to go, **but** the animation is and sequencing is weird, http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/MKrMdr/?editors=0110

Comment: The sliding is responding to `translateXamount = -100`, not to `sliderInnerWrapper.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)';` I want it to first go to -50% then animate to 0. I think that's a recipe for a regular slider, which is what I'm trying to create.

Comment: Did you want 2 slides at a time? That's why you only want 50% to the left? when previous slide goes to 0, then it's display: none after that, so there's a visible hiccup (a jerkiness) instead of a smooth animation. Normally, a slider will link the slides end to end so a slideshow of 20 slides at 300px width each would wrap the slides in a 6000px wide div. Try making the outer-wrapper 1200 pixel with `dispaly: table` and make each slide `display: table-cell`

Comment: I want 1 slide at a time. Can you please show me what you mean in an updated codepen?